# Integrate Java selenium with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium

In my Java selenium application for running automation testscripts, I want to integrate with Spring/Spring boot to use make use of .properties files for different environment to run.
Is there any example or how to proceed, I have seen many links , but not able to find the correct way of implementing it.
Depending on the environment the app is in, it should pick the corresponding .properties file.

ReadConfigurations.java // Where it should read the properties file and get some values like,

```java
public class ReadConfigurations  {
//  @Value( "${local.driverpath}" )
//  private String getdriverpath;

//  @Value( "${login_name}" )
//    String getLoginName;

}
```

application-local.properties

```properties
local.driverpath = ..\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe
local.implicit_wait_time=30
local.app_url = http://localhost:8080/app
local.login_name= 
local.login_password =
```

application-test.properties

```properties
local.driverpath = ..\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe
local.implicit_wait_time=30
local.app_url = http://testurl:8080/app
local.login_name= 
local.login_password =
```

```java
public class LoginTest {
ReadConfigurations readConfigurations;

    @Test
    private void login() throws  InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readConfigurations.getDriverPath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For running tests, I assume you want to read properties from `test` package.

So, annotate your `ReadConfigurations` with `@Configuration` and `@TestPropertySource`

```
@Configuration
@TestPropertySource("application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
public class ReadConfigurations {

    // this should be added to resolve ${..}
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Value( "${local.driverpath}" )
    String getDriverPath;

    @Value( "${local.login_name}" )
    String getLoginName;

    ...

}
```

Then start your tests with `local` or `test` spring profile.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

```
@SpringBootTest
public class LoginTest {

@Autowired
ReadConfigurations readConfigurations;

    @Test
    private void login() throws  InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", readConfigurations.getDriverPath);
    }

}
```

This worked for me for the Getting started Spring Boot project:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/tree/main/initial

```
./mvnw test -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

Comment: it is not picking up the properties file.  -Dspring.profiles.active=test is set IN  Maven pROFILE?

Comment: No, maven profile is not used, just system property. 

I've tested this multiple times and it worked.. Where is your properties file location? In my case: `src/test/resources/application-local.properties`, `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`.

Comment: I have .properties in srs/test/resources. However I need to use Maven to run ...

Comment: I've also run this with maven, maven wrapper was available in the spring-boot project template, so I've used `./mvnw` for run maven commands, but running `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=test` also worked for me. I can suggest run `mvn clean` and also double-check for typos.. I expect  `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=test` should work for you.

Comment: I was able to run thru Maven, but still ReadConfigurations .java is not picking the properties. Should that class be also in src/test/java. I feel that it should be in srs/main/java

Comment: `ReadConfigurations` also placed in `src/test/java`, I'll be able to share my project structure screenshot tomorrow... Also note I'm using spring-boot 2.5.0. Actually I just cloned this repo https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot/tree/main/initial and created a few files here just to check this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240947/discussion-between-max-daroshchanka-and-user1015388).

Comment: @ Max, thanks, I will take a look at it